# Yii cgridview last page pagination issue

Tags: php, pagination, yii1.x

I have simple Yii cgridview code with pagination. Pagination is working fine but in the last page I have faced one issue.

For example, If I have 13 records in DB table, and set pagination for 10 pages per page then for first page It will show **"1 - 10 of 13 results"** but when I clicked on 2nd page link then It will show **"4 - 13 of 13"** instead of **"11 - 13 of 13"**.

Here is my code.

1) Controller :

```
function actiontransactionHistory(){
        $creditTransactionObj = new CreditTransaction();

        $this->render('history',array(
            'creditTransactionObj'=>$creditTransactionObj,
        ));
    }
```

2) Model :

```
public function search()
    {
        // Warning: Please modify the following code to remove attributes that
        // should not be searched.

        $criteria=new CDbCriteria;

        $criteria->compare('id',$this->id,true);
        $criteria->compare('fkasmtGroupId',$this->fkasmtGroupId);
        $criteria->compare('fkgroupSurveyUserId',$this->fkgroupSurveyUserId,true);
        $criteria->compare('fkasmtId',$this->fkasmtId);
        $criteria->compare('transaction_type',$this->transaction_type);
        $criteria->compare('credit_type',$this->credit_type,true);
        $criteria->compare('credit_qty',$this->credit_qty);
        $criteria->compare('transaction_date',$this->transaction_date,true);
        $criteria->compare('isDelete',$this->isDelete);
        $criteria->compare('status',$this->status);
        $criteria->compare('created_at',$this->created_at,true);
        $criteria->compare('modified_at',$this->modified_at,true);

        $sort = array(
            "defaultOrder" => "transaction_date DESC",
        );

        return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
            "criteria"=>$criteria,
            "sort" => $sort,
        ));
    }
```

3) View:

```
<?php
        $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
            'id' => 'history-grid',
            'dataProvider' => $creditTransactionObj->search(),
            'loadingCssClass' => '',
            'enableSorting' => true,
            'itemsCssClass' => 'my-teams',
            'summaryText' => "Displaying {start} - {end} of {count} results.",
            "emptyText" => "There is no transaction history available.",
            'columns' => array(
                array('name' => 'transaction_date', 'header' => 'Date', 'type' => 'raw', 'value' => 'date("d-M-Y",strtotime($data->transaction_date))', 'htmlOptions' => array('class' => '')),
                array('name' => 'credit_qty', 'header' => '# of Credits', 'sortable'=>false, 'type' => 'raw', 'value' => '($data->transaction_type == 1) ? - $data->credit_qty : $data->credit_qty', 'htmlOptions' => array('class' => '')),
                array('name' => 'credit_type', 'header' => 'Type', 'type' => 'raw', 'value' => '$data->credit_type', 'htmlOptions' => array('class' => '')),
                array('name' => 'transaction_type', 'header' => 'Activity', 'type' => 'raw', 'value' => '($data->transaction_type == 0) ? "Purchased" : (($data->transaction_type == 1) ? "Spent" : "Refunded")', 'htmlOptions' => array('class' => '')),
                array('name' => 'fkasmtGroupId', 'header' => 'Group Name', 'type' => 'raw', 'value' => array($this,'getGroupName'), 'htmlOptions' => array('width' => '35%')),
            )
        ));
    ?>
```

I have also attached both pages screenshot.

[image]

[image]

Any help will be appreciate. Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After spending lots of hours finally I found the solution for this issue.
Actually the problem was in **fetchData()** function which is used in 
**yii/framework/web/CActiveDataProvider.php** framework class file.

In **fetchData()** method, limit was not calculated properly for the last page pagination. so I have made changes to calculate correct limit.

**Old Code:**

```
protected function fetchData()
{
    $criteria=clone $this->getCriteria();

    if(($pagination=$this->getPagination())!==false)
    {
        $pagination->setItemCount($this->getTotalItemCount());
        $pagination->applyLimit($criteria);
    }

    $baseCriteria=$this->model->getDbCriteria(false);

    if(($sort=$this->getSort())!==false)
    {
        // set model criteria so that CSort can use its table alias setting
        if($baseCriteria!==null)
        {
            $c=clone $baseCriteria;
            $c->mergeWith($criteria);
            $this->model->setDbCriteria($c);
        }
        else
            $this->model->setDbCriteria($criteria);
        $sort->applyOrder($criteria);
    }

    $this->model->setDbCriteria($baseCriteria!==null ? clone $baseCriteria : null);
    $data=$this->model->findAll($criteria);
    $this->model->setDbCriteria($baseCriteria);  // restore original criteria
    return $data;
}
```

**New Code:**

```
protected function fetchData()
{
        $criteria=clone $this->getCriteria();

        if(($pagination=$this->getPagination())!==false)
        {
                $pagination->setItemCount($this->getTotalItemCount());
                $pagination->applyLimit($criteria);
                // update limit to the correct value for the last page 
                $limit=$pagination->getLimit();
                $offset=$pagination->getOffset();
                if ( $offset+$limit > $pagination->getItemCount() )
                        $criteria->limit = $pagination->getItemCount() - $offset;

        }
        $baseCriteria=$this->model->getDbCriteria(false);

        if(($sort=$this->getSort())!==false)
        {
                // set model criteria so that CSort can use its table alias setting
                if($baseCriteria!==null)
                {
                        $c=clone $baseCriteria;
                        $c->mergeWith($criteria);
                        $this->model->setDbCriteria($c);
                }
                else
                        $this->model->setDbCriteria($criteria);
                $sort->applyOrder($criteria);
        }

        $this->model->setDbCriteria($baseCriteria!==null ? clone $baseCriteria : null);
        $data=$this->model->findAll($criteria);
        $this->model->setDbCriteria($baseCriteria);  // restore original criteria
        return $data;
}
```

But remember, never update a core class file of framework. so I just extend this method in my Model file and write below code.

**Final Code In My Model file without change in framework file:**

```
class CustomActiveDataProvider extends CActiveDataProvider
{
        /**
         * Fetches the data from the persistent data storage.
         * @return array list of data items
         */
        protected function fetchData()
        {
                $criteria=clone $this->getCriteria();

                if(($pagination=$this->getPagination())!==false)
                {
                        $pagination->setItemCount($this->getTotalItemCount());
                        $pagination->applyLimit($criteria);
                        // update limit to the correct value for the last page 
                        $limit=$pagination->getLimit();
                        $offset=$pagination->getOffset();
                        if ( $offset+$limit > $pagination->getItemCount() )
                                $criteria->limit = $pagination->getItemCount() - $offset;

                }
                $baseCriteria=$this->model->getDbCriteria(false);

                if(($sort=$this->getSort())!==false)
                {
                        // set model criteria so that CSort can use its table alias setting
                        if($baseCriteria!==null)
                        {
                                $c=clone $baseCriteria;
                                $c->mergeWith($criteria);
                                $this->model->setDbCriteria($c);
                        }
                        else
                                $this->model->setDbCriteria($criteria);
                        $sort->applyOrder($criteria);
                }

                $this->model->setDbCriteria($baseCriteria!==null ? clone $baseCriteria : null);
                $data=$this->model->findAll($criteria);
                $this->model->setDbCriteria($baseCriteria);  // restore original criteria
                return $data;
        }

}

// Used this custome active data provider as shown in below.
public function search()
{
    $criteria=new CDbCriteria;

    $criteria->compare('id',$this->id,true);
    $criteria->compare('isDelete',$this->isDelete);
    $criteria->compare('status',$this->status);
    $criteria->compare('created_at',$this->created_at,true);
    $criteria->compare('modified_at',$this->modified_at,true);

    $sort = array(
        "defaultOrder" => "transaction_date DESC",
    );

    return new CustomActiveDataProvider($this, array(
        "criteria"=>$criteria,
        "sort" => $sort,
        "pagination" => array('pageSize' => (isset($_REQUEST['pageSize'])?$_REQUEST['pageSize']:10))
    ));
}
```

After this change, Last page pagination works completely fine.
Thanks!